# Searching and sorting through an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I am a new Java programmer and I am working on a project that requires me to read a text file that has Movie Reviews.

Once I've read the file, I am asked to search and sort through the Array of movies and return the total number of reviews for each movie as well as the average rate for each movie.

The portion I am currently stuck on is iterating through the Array list.

I am using an inner and outer for loop and I seem to be getting an infinite loop.

I would appreciate a second set of eyes. I have been staring at this project for a few days now and starting to not see mistakes.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class MovieReviewApp {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String strline = "";
    String[] result = null;
    final String delimit = "\\s+\\|\\s+";
    String title ="";
    //int rating = (Integer.valueOf(- 1));

    ArrayList<MovieReview> movies = new ArrayList<MovieReview>();
    //ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    //ArrayList<Integer> ratings = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //ListMultimap<String, Integer> hm = ArrayListMultimap.create();

   try
   {

      BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/deborahjaffe/Desktop/Java/midterm/movieReviewData.txt"));

        while(true)
        {
            strline = f.readLine(); // reads line by line of text file

            if(strline == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            result = strline.split(delimit, 2); //creates two strings

            //hm.put(result[0], new Integer [] {Integer.valueOf(result[1])});
            //hm.put(result[0], Integer.valueOf(result[1]));

            // titles.add(result[0]);
            //ratings.add(Integer.valueOf(result[1]));

            MovieReview m = new MovieReview(result[0]);
            movies.add(m);
            MovieReview m2 = new MovieReview();

            int rating = Integer.valueOf(result[1]);
            int sz = movies.size();


            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
                {
                    m2 = movies.get(i);

                   if (movies.contains(m2))
                   {
                       m2.addRating(rating);
                   }

                   else
                   {
                       movies.add(m2);
                       m2.addRating(rating);
                   }
               }
            }

            movies.toString();

            //Collections.sort(movies);

       } //end while

       f.close();

       //Set<String> keys = hm.keySet();
       //Collection<Integer> values = hm.values();

    } //end of try

    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: File not found");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening a file.");
    }

} // end main

} // end class
```

Comment: I'm on a phone so the code is hard to read but you have while true. That's an intentional infinite loop is it not?

Comment: It doesn't look like an infinite loop, but you did set up an exponential loop structure. At 1,000 movies you'll be adding a million reviews and it will only get worse. You might want to try a subset (like 5-10) of the movies so you can find all the bugs in your code.

Comment: @DeborahJaffe I suggest you have a quick look at my answer especially the portion regarding having a Scanner instead of BufferedReader for better efficiency and more versatility. Regarding your problem you mentioned in Sujan Reedy A's answer, can you please expand on it? I understand it is not being properly read, but perhaps input versus output from the code would be more useful in figuring out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file first and then iterate through the list or map for searching, sorting etc. In the above code, close the while loop before iterating through the list.

Comment: I had tried this previously but was having issues with my ratings array list not be properly being read outside the while loop. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through the `ArrayList` you can use an enhanced `for-loop` to iterate through it. Note: while in an enhanced `for-loop` you **cannot** make changes to the `ArrayList` as the enhanced `for-loop` makes the `ArrayList` essentially (and temporarily) read-only. This would work for iterating through to pull values, but not for adding values. Because you are changing the `ArrayList` this won't work, but I just thought that you should know about it, if you don't already. The enhanced `for-loop` works like this, I will put separate parts in squiggle brackets,
`for({Object Type of ArrayList} {Dummy Value} : {name of ArrayList}),` so it would look like this: `for(MovieReview x: movies)`.

Regarding the inner part of this nested `for-loop`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
            {
                m2 = movies.get(i);

               if (movies.contains(m2))
               {
                   m2.addRating(rating);
               }

               else
               {
                   movies.add(m2);
                   m2.addRating(rating);
               }
           }
        }
```

Why do you have the inner part? The `j` variable is never used for anything so the `for-loop` seems kind of useless. Unless of course you made a mistake at the top of the inner loop and meant to have `m2 = movies.get(j);` but that seems unlikely.

In regard to the infinite loop, the way you wrote the `for-loops` you should not be getting an infinite loop because they all increment to a certain value that is reachable. Your `while-loop` seems to run infinitely, but I do notice that you have a `break` if `strline` points to null. I assume this is guaranteed to occur at the end of the file, but I would suggest that you make the condition for your `while-loop` be `while(scannerName.hasNext())`. This will allow your `while-loop` to eventually terminate without having the extra code plus having a `Scanner` instead of a `BufferedReader` will be slightly more efficient and still do everything the `BufferedReader` can do and much more, like that method `hasNext()`.

I hope this has helped. If you have other questions, let me know. Good luck.